# How to pass arguments to a docker container at start when running an image of dot net core console

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, dockerfile, console-application

I've created a container of my netcore 2.2 console app.
The main function must receive 2 arguments in order to start.
If 2 arguments are not passed an exception will be thrown.

I'm running docker on windows.

This is my docker file:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2
COPY bin/Release/netcoreapp2.2/publish/ app/
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "app/BinanceLoggerCandleStick.dll"]
```

This is my main function in the console app, yes nothing special but it needs two arguments
ie in this case "BTCUSDT" and "1min"

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
//some code
}
```

I've tried running the image/container with the following command, but nothing:

```
docker start thirsty_bose "BTCUSDT" "1min"
```

I don't want to hardcode the arguments in the dockerfile, I want to pass them with docker start command.
How can I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways of passing an argument. If you need to pass it at the build-time of image please use `--build-arg VAR=VALUE`

> Reference:- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg

Or If you want to pass at run time, please use ENV and pass it when you run `docker run` command.

> Reference:- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env